# fwrite() fails without writing anything to existing file

Tags: c++, c

Sorry for this basic problem guys, but I'm having an issue just getting `fwrite()` to work properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    FILE* fd = NULL;
    fd = fopen("out","rw");

    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Open failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int error = 0;

    printf("Attempting write ... \n");
    char buff[] = {"hello?\n"};

    if( (error = fwrite(buff, 1, 7, fd)) != 7 ) {
        printf("fwrite() failed with code %d \n", error);
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

This code fails - `fwrite()` just returns 0 when it should return 7 instead for seven 1b characters written to the file. The file does exist in the same directory; I've tried this with the full file path instead; I've chmod'd the output file `out` to 777 in case that was the issue (it wasn't); `fread()` and `fseek()` both work as expected but I've taken them out for brevity.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this seems like a `c` question instead of `c++`, you should correct the tag

Comment: @appleapple you're right - I have to use C libs in certain parts of the code, but the overall project I'm working for is technically using C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopen` do not have `"rw"` mode, and you should open the file in binary mode since you `fwrite` to it.

What you want is `"wb"`, `"w+b"` or `"r+b"`

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I thought the modes would go together (as in "r" and "w" together should be "rw"). My error was literally as simple as changing "rw" to "r+" :/

Answer (score 0):

```
fd = fopen("out","rw");
```

"rw" is not one of the valid open modes.

See the [fopen(3) manual page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/fopen.3.html) for more information.

You did not specify your platform, or C library. On Linux, this `fopen()` call fails.